# How can I stop observing an observable without disposing it in RxJava2?

Tags: java, rx-java, rx-java2, dispose

I have an unusual issue with RxJava2.

Basically we have a following scenario:

- User takes a picture and by pressing next starts network request
- After network request is finished a method in ViewModel is executed, which triggers UI action
- User at any time can **press back button**, which should restart a flow and even if previous photo is uploaded successfully it **should not trigger** any actions.

Now typically I would put all my code in CompositeDisposable and call clear() or dispose () depending on my case. This **will stop observation of uploaded photo** after uses presses back button.

However, I can’t call clear() or dispose() in this case, because it **would terminate network reques**t! Photo is usually 1-2 mb and by calling dispose it would terminate network request...
How can I stop observing previous flow and observe only future uploads, without terminating previous upload?

I know that there is should be some kind of way to notify my observable that user pressed a back button, but all my attempts seems hacky and not clean. I would like to learn a correct way of handling such case.

Comment: i think you need `switchMap` here. You can read article https://medium.com/appunite-edu-collection/rxjava-flatmap-switchmap-and-concatmap-differences-examples-6d1f3ff88ee0

Comment: @borichellow I thought about switchMap, but don't know can I construct in a such a way, that dispose would not clear subscribtion

Answer (score 1):

The correct way in my opinion is to use `takeUntil` so you get to cancel the current upload and it completes at that point. Then you need to use `repeat` to re-subscribe again for future uploads.

Something like this:

```
compositeDisposable += nextButtonClicked
        .firstOrError()
        .flatMapCompletable {
          networkUpload.takeUntil(backButtonClicked).ignoreElements()
        }.repeat().subscribe()
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you mean I should pass some subject into takeUntil argument, which would be triggered when I need to stop observing uploads?

Comment: Correct, you need a way to stop the upload. That Subject will trigger upon pressing a "Cancel" button that you have in your UI for instance.

Comment: but I don't wan't to stop uploading... I need to stop observing response from uploaded file instead of terminating network request.

Comment: There's no such thing as stop observing in Rx, you are either subscribed or unsubscribed. If you want to ignore the response for a given "cancelled" upload then you'll have to `filter` once you get the response from the upload to determine whether you want to process it or not.